# Swift: Maps: How to tell next intersecting street on my route

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps

I am writing an iOS app in swift. I need to be able to tell at any given point in time what street will be intersecting next on my user's route who is driving/walking.

I am able to find the street name user is currently on, the direction user is moving in and also the current coordinates but the last step stumps me: which street will intersect next?

I am open to using Apple Maps, Google Maps, OSM etc as long as it if free.

Comment: I am not sure if it will help, but the closest thing I could find was this, some options are about the (next crossing street).
http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

The idea is to get the legs of the directions and then determine in which leg you are currently in which you can do since you know the current street name you are in and then find the info about the next leg. It may not always be accurate but its the easiest way that you can find which street will intersect.
You can either use the Driving or Waypoints api. 
Hope this helps.